# How to configure Prettier to format Styled Components conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, formatting, eslint, styled-components, prettier

I'm using Prettier, Eslint and Styled components - backtick style declaration. 
It works so far but Prettier formats the conditional rendering of the Styled components in the way that Eslint doesn't allow and after the formatting Eslint starts to complain and the build fails.

Let me show you the problem via code.

Initial code before Prettier handling:

```
// styled components styles apply
const TextInputStyled = styled(TextInputThemed)`
  ${(props: StyledProps) => {
    const {
      theme: { theme10x },
      disabled,
      success,
      error,
    } = props;
    return `
      ${success && `
        border-color: ${theme10x.palette.common.success};
      `};

      ${error && `
        background-color: ${theme10x.palette.common.error};
      `};

      ${disabled && `
        background-color: ${theme10x.palette.background.disabled};
      `};
    `;
  }}
```

After Prettier Handling:

```
// styled components styles apply
const TextInputStyled = styled(TextInputThemed)`
  ${(props: StyledProps) => {
    const {
      theme: { theme10x },
      disabled,
      success,
      error,
    } = props;
    return `
      ${
        success &&
        `
        border-color: ${theme10x.palette.common.success};
      `
      };

      ${
        error &&
        `
        background-color: ${theme10x.palette.common.error};
      `
      };

      ${
        disabled &&
        `
        background-color: ${theme10x.palette.background.disabled};
      `
      };
    `;
  }}
`;
```

After that Eslint starts to complain:

```
  133:1   error    Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 8        indent
  133:19  error    '&&' should be placed at the beginning of the line  operator-linebreak
  137:1   error    Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 6        indent
  140:1   error    Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 8        indent
  140:17  error    '&&' should be placed at the beginning of the line  operator-linebreak
  144:1   error    Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 6        indent
  147:1   error    Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 8        indent
  147:20  error    '&&' should be placed at the beginning of the line  operator-linebreak
  151:1   error    Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 6        indent
```

I wouldn't like to change Eslint rules because they are really useful in the 'real' use cases.
So is there exists any way to solve this problem correctly? 
Thanks for any help!

Update:

My .eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0, 
    "react/static-property-placement": 0,

    "quotes": [2, "single"],
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "comma-dangle": 0,
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "react/state-in-constructor": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": 0,
    "semi": 1,
    "comma-dangle:": 0,
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "import/extensions": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
      1,
      {
        "extensions": [".jsx", ".tsx"]
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 0
  }
}
```

My Prettier config (it's a part of the package.json)

```
  "prettier": {
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true
  }
```

I'm running it as a git hook via husky in a chain with lint:fix

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint:fix && pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  },
```

Comment: What are your `eslint` config settings? How are you running Prettier - as part of a script, or automatically as part of e.g. VSCode?

Comment: Hi Jered. Thank you for the good notice. Please, check my updates.

Comment: Prettier makes `styled-components` uglier

Comment: Did you end up finding a working solution for this? Facing the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not and it was a bit annoying

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered trying `eslint-config-prettier`?

From the Prettier [install](https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html#eslint-and-other-linters) docs:

> If you use ESLint, install eslint-config-prettier to make ESLint and Prettier play nice with each other. It turns off all ESLint rules that are unnecessary or might conflict with Prettier.

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/blob/main/index.js), it appears it would turn off the `indent` and `operator-linebreak` rules ESLint is complaining about.

---

I see you noted:

> I wouldn't like to change Eslint rules because they are really useful in the 'real' use cases.

Are these two rules truly useful? They seem to fall into the category of "formatting rules" rather than "code-quality rules", and so I wonder what the harm is in allowing Prettier to do what it's built for. ([Reference](https://prettier.io/docs/en/comparison.html))

It seems to me your problem comes from using ESLint and Prettier, but leaving them with an overlap in their responsibilities (which `eslint-config-prettier` could address).

### Alternate Solution

If you **really** want to go the other direction and modify Prettier's behavior, perhaps you can ignore the files or use inline comments: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html